# Is there some sort of null IOStream in Julia?

Tags: julia

In the Julia module I'm working on, I need to be able to store multiple files that I can write to dynamically at different parts in the code.
So I've created a mutable struct that looks something like this.

```
mutable struct foo
    file_1::IOStream
    file_2::IOStream
    file_3::IOStream
end
```

how would I go about initialising something like this before I generate the IOStream, I've tried the following, but they don't seem to work.

```
foobar = foo(undef,undef,undef)

foobar = foo(nothing, nothing, nothing)

foobar = foo(0,0,0)
```

But none of them seem to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to allow for creation of an uninitialized `mutable struct` you can define an inner constructor fro example like this:

```
mutable struct foo
    file_1::IOStream
    file_2::IOStream
    file_3::IOStream

    foo() = new()
end
```

And now when you have:

```
julia> foobar = foo()
foo(#undef, #undef, #undef)
```

Of course before accessing fields of `foobar` you have to assign some value to it.

You can check if field of `foobar` is assigned using `isdefined`, e.g. `isdefined(foobar, :field_1)`. The only small inconvenience is that `isdefined` will also work if you write something like `isdefined(foobar, :field_100)` and return `false` (so you have to be sure that you are checking an existing field, e.g. by using the `fieldnames` function or the `hasfield` function; the latter is available only in Julia 1.2)

An alternative is to define `foo` in the following way:

```
mutable struct foo
    file_1::Union{IOStream, Nothing}
    file_2::Union{IOStream, Nothing}
    file_3::Union{IOStream, Nothing}

    foo(file_1=nothing, file_2=nothing, file_3=nothing) =
        new(file_1, file_2, file_3)
end
```

(you could omit defining an inner constructor in this case)

Now you can write:

```
julia> foobar = foo()
foo(nothing, nothing, nothing)
```

The benefit of this approach is that you can safely access fields of `foobar` and test for their value, e.g.:

```
julia> foobar.file_1 === nothing
true
```

**EDIT**

Returning to your original question from another angle there is a `devnull` variable that discards all data written to it. However its type is `Base.DevNull` which is a subtype of `IO`. Therefore, you could also write:

```
mutable struct foo
    file_1::Union{IOStream, Base.DevNull}
    file_2::Union{IOStream, Base.DevNull}
    file_3::Union{IOStream, Base.DevNull}

    foo() = new(devnull, devnull, devnull)
end
```

In this way you can write to `file_1`, `file_2` and `file_3` all the time and by default what you write is discarded.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I was quite busy.

But this seems more useful than my answer

Answer (score 0):

I found out I can make an empty IOStream ans edit it late so that it would look something like this:

```
foobar = foo(IOStream(string()),IOStream(string()),IOStream(string()))
```